# Is there any way to use `.pkl` sklearn model in Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

If dataframe using pandas, here's what I did

```
import joblib
lgbm_v5 = joblib.load('model.pkl')
b = lgbm_v5.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Is there any way to use `.pkl` sklearn model in Pyspark DataFrame?

Comment: check pandas_udf, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with a simple sentiment analysis to get you started.

Once you get the hang of it, it can be become much more elaborated for even better performance (pandas_udf, preds over vectorized numpy  arrays).

```
from functools import partial

import joblib
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType, ArrayType


class SentimentModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokenizer = load_model("tokenizer")
        self.vectorizer = load_model("vectorizer")
        self.classifier = load_model("classifier")


def load_model(name):
    return joblib.load(...) # load your model from disk or whatever

def predict_text(text, model):
    try:
        tokens = model.tokenizer(text)
        vectors = model.vectorizer.transform([t for t in tokens])
        sentiment = model.classifier.predict_proba(vectors)
    except ValueError:
        sentiment = [0.5, 0.5]
    return sentiment


model = SentimentModel()
partial_transform = partial(predict_text, model=model)
prediction_udf = udf(partial_transform, ArrayType(FloatType()))
predictions_df = df.withColumn("probabilities", prediction_udf(df.text))
```